# Sublime Text 3: Error trying to parse settings, unexpected character

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm trying to change the size of the text in Sublime 3, but I get an error. My screen looks like this:

[image: Screenshot 1]

The error dialog I see is this:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And please don't post pictures of code or error messages, post the text directly here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Add a comma after the theme setting.

```
"theme": "Default.sublime-theme",
```

Also after the font face setting. Every setting needs to have a comma after it, that's how JSON works.
[More about JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)